# date() off by a day?

Tags: php, date, stripe-payments

I'm working with a Stripe timestamp. If I cancel a test subscription, the timestamp Stripe returns for when the subscription will cancel ("cancel_at") is 1591754579. Stripe says this is June 10.

If I take that number and do this:

```
echo date("F j, Y") . "<br>";
echo date("F j, Y", 1591754579);
```

On my server I will get:

```
May 10, 2020
June 9, 2020
```

If I put the same code into a W3Schools PHP "Try It Now" window, I'll get:

```
May 10, 2020
June 10, 2020
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Comment: Timezone.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A time zone settings example

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . chr(10);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Here the time zones list
https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php